# taken float from terminal is left without a coma

Tags: c#, terminal, decimal

I am new in C# and I try take a value float from console but it is left without a decimal point.

This is my code:

```
do {
    Console.Write("Promedio:\t");
    promedio = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    if (promedio < 0.0 || promedio > 5.0) {
        Console.WriteLine("Error: >> Promedio incorrecto, digite un valor entre 0.0 y 5.0\n");
    }
} while (promedio < 0 || promedio > 5);
```

If I write 3.7 and if print promedio (average) then it looks like this:

> 37

Besides, in the code above while for ever say promedio is wrong.

What is the error? Any suggestions or recommendations?

Comment: I can't see anywhere in your code where you are printing any numeric value to the console. Is this really all of your code?

Comment: I copied and pasted your code into a blank Main and added `var promedio = 0.0F;` above it and it ran fine when I entered 3.7. It exited the do-while loop and the debugger showed promedio as 3.7

Comment: Perhaps a locale issue? try `float.Parse(Console.ReadLine(), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Float, System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo)`

Comment: `and if print promedio` - what code do use for that?

Comment: Also, you probably want to check `float.IsInfinity` and `float.IsNaN` because your while loop will exit on those conditions.

Comment: if I do `promedio = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine(), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Any, System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo);` (System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Float threw an error for me) and enter 3,7 then promedio is 37 in the debugger. Not sure I am must use beyond this, I have no experience coding for cultures.

Comment: It has to do with the decimal separator the current culture has defined, in your case is may be the `,`.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this before the `do{}while();`

```
CultureInfo ci = (CultureInfo)Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Clone();
ci.NumberFormat.DecimalNumberSeparator = ".";
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = ci;
```

Now the separator used to parse the float is the "." so the `3.7` should be successfully parsed into the number you want. Hope it helps.

Comment: I believe the OP may be Spanish and want to use the comma decimal separator.

Comment: @spodger the sample input the OP gives is `3.7`, that's way I'm suggesting changing the `,` by `.`

Comment: It is definitely a localization/culture issue